# My code opens the link three times, how do I limit it to one?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, python-webbrowser

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import webbrowser

def sign_in(meetinglink):
    webbrowser.open(meetinglink)  
  
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/3021118/Applications/Meeting-Launcher/timings.csv')

while True:
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    if now in str(df['timings']):
        row = df.loc[df['timings'] == now]
        m_link = str(row.iloc[0,1])

        sign_in(m_link)
        time.sleep(10)
        print('MEETING JOINED!')
```

This program gets a link from a .csv file, opens it at a certain time (which is specified in the .csv file) and outputs "MEETING JOINED!" every time it does that. Though, it opens the link and outputs "MEETING JOINED!" three times, each after a short break. How can I stop it from doing this three times?

Comment: Your sleep time is 10 seconds + the time to execute the logic, so in the same minute as the scheduled meeting this code is going to run around 4+ times. Once the meeting link is opened, mark it as done using a flag or something, so that it's not picked in the next loop

Comment: you can use break to end the routine if the code to only run until  you log in